# error: expected a ";" using std::vector<...>::const_iterator uninformative compilation error?

Tags: c++

In the context of creating a hopefully better OO wrapper around the [nlopt](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) optimization library where the objective and constraint functions signature and implementation can be defined using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) types I have the following problem:

This compiles:

```
namespace nlopt {
template <class Data>
struct Oracle {
    typedef boost::tuple<double, VectorXd>   (*f_t) (const VectorXd&, Data& data);
    typedef boost::tuple<VectorXd, MatrixXd> (*mf_t)(const VectorXd&, Data& data);
};
};

/// Concrete Nlopt adapter search space implementation.
/**
 * Concrete Nlopt adapter search space implementation.
 */
template <class ConstraintData>
class NloptSpace : public ContinuousSpaceInterface<double, VectorXd> {
public:
    /// nonlinear constraints
    struct NonlinearConstraint {
        typename nlopt::Oracle<ConstraintData>::f_t func_; ConstraintData* data_; double tol_;
        NonlinearConstraint(typename nlopt::Oracle<ConstraintData>::f_t func, ConstraintData* data, double tol) {
            func_ = func;
            data_ = data;
            tol_ = tol;
        }
    };
    // ...
};

typedef typename NloptSpace<ConstraintData>::NonlinearConstraint NonLinearConstraint;
const std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>& inequality_constraints = space.inequality_constraints();
```

However, this extra line does not compile and gives me the following totally uninformative error:

```
std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator iter;

error: expected a ";"
     std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator iter;
                                                 ^
```

btw just in case you are wondering whether I have the correct includes this also compiles:

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter;
```

and this also compiles:

```
inequality_constraints.begin(); // can't assign it to anything without the compiler error
```

Somehow the compiler doesn't like the `NonLinearConstraint` template as a vector const iterator but it really doesn't give any hint as to what's wrong.

I don't expect anyone to help me fix the issue here but to give me a pointer how to get more information on this compiler error.

Comment: Please show a complete example that reproduces the error. Out-of-context lines are not helpful.

Comment: I of course thought about including something self-contained but it would be too much. I am giving you many examples of what compiles but that line I can't get any information on the error.

Comment: Let me guess, `ConstraintData` is a template parameter?

Comment: It looks to me like OP is deceiving us. Shouldn't the last two lines be inside the definition of `class NloptSpace`? It doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: It is not enough to think about including a self-contained example. It is important to actually include it. Reducing your code to a manageable size could require considerable work, but there's no substitute to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator` is a dependent name - it depends on the template parameter `ConstraintData`. The standard says that (§14.6 [name.res]/p2):

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
>   dependent on a *template-parameter* is assumed not to name a type
>   unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is
>   qualified by the keyword `typename`.

Therefore, you need to use

```
  typename std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator iter;
//^^^^^^^^
```

Otherwise, the compiler considers `std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator` to not name a type (for all it knows, there can be a specialization of `std::vector` that defines a member variable called `const_iterator`).

Modern compilers tend to give better error messages for this, though. g++ 4.8, for instance, produces:

```
test.cpp:46:2: error: need 'typename' before 'std::vector<typename NloptSpace<ConstraintData>::NonlinearConstraint>::const_iterator' because 'std::vector<typename NloptSpace<ConstraintData>::NonlinearConstraint>' is a dependent scope
  std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator iter;
  ^
test.cpp:46:51: error: expected ';' before 'iter'
  std::vector<NonLinearConstraint>::const_iterator iter;
```

Comment: Indeed, this solves the compilation error, no idea why though :(

Comment: @GiovanniAzua, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords